# Time Function in Progress 4GL

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I would like to insert 2 shift timings to the code.

1. (First Shift)
   Shift starts from 8:00:00:000 to 19:59:59:999
2. (Second Shift)
   Shift Starts from 20:00:00:000 to next day 7:59:59:999

I need to get the above exact data to be added to the below code. 
Please help.
Below is the code:

```
IF TIME < (20 * 60 * 60)  THEN  DO: 
     ASSIGN StartDDT = dt_tm2dec(DATE(TODAY), 0)
            EndDDT   = dt_tm2dec(DATE(TODAY),19 * 60 * 60 + 59 * 60 + 59).
END.
ELSE DO: 
    ASSIGN StartDDT = dt_tm2dec(DATE(TODAY),20 * 60 * 60).
            EndDDT  = dt_tm2dec(DATE(TODAY + 1),07 * 60 * 60 + 59 * 60 + 59).
END.
```

Comment: TIME only returns whole seconds.  If you truly need a millisecond component (which I do not see a need for as the question is currently stated, but you did sort of hint at it in your description) then you would need to use a function like NOW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The conditions you specified can be written as:

```
if ( time >= ( 8 * 60 * 60 )) and ( time < ( 20 * 60 * 60 )) then 
  do:
    message "first shift".
  end.
 else
  do:
    message "second shift".
  end.
```

Comment: Thanks Tom, as per my code logic, the second shift ends at next day 7:59:59 AM.
Will there be an issue if I update the code like below:

ELSE
  DO:
    ASSIGN StartDDT = dt_tm2dec(DATE(TODAY),20 * 60 * 60).
                EndDDT  = dt_tm2dec(DATE(TODAY + 1),07 * 60 * 60 + 59 * 60 + 59).
  END.

Comment: That depends on what the dt_tm2dec() function does and how the resulting data is used elsewhere in your code.  It seems like your assignments will probably do what you want them to if the rest of the code is consistent with this small sample.

Comment: DEFINE VARIABLE StartDDT        AS DECIMAL      NO-UNDO.
ASSIGN  StartDDT = dt_tm2dec(PreviousDate, PTinSec)
               EndDDT   = dt_tm2dec(CURRENTDATE,CTinSec).

Above are the things which I DEFINED and ASSIGNED.

Comment: Yes, I know that.  But what I do not know is how any of this works with the rest of your code.  Given what you have shown and assuming reasonable behavior of the code that this example probably fits into then, yes, what you are doing will probably work the way that you expect it too.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `DATETIME` datatype to get millisecond accuracy on your times. Build the shift times with the `DATETIME` function, then compare your time to them. The `NOW` function gives you the current time down to the millisecond:

```
DEFINE VARIABLE dtShift1 AS DATETIME NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE dtShift2 AS DATETIME NO-UNDO.

ASSIGN
    dtShift1 = DATETIME(TODAY, (8 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
    dtShift2 = DATETIME(TODAY, (20 * 60 * 60 * 1000)).

IF NOW >= dtShift1 AND NOW < dtShift2 THEN
    MESSAGE "First shift" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.
ELSE
    MESSAGE "Second shift" VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX INFORMATION.
```

You can also check the shift time for the following day by adding a day to `TODAY`:

```
dtShift1 = DATETIME(TODAY + 1, (8 * 60 * 60 * 1000))
```

And if you need to handle different time zones, use the `DATETIME-TZ` datatype.